# Adding columns after condensing rows php sql

Tags: php, sql

[original table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vngs8.png)

I condensed it with

`SELECT type_value, number FROM parts_usage GROUP BY number, type_value`

to get [result of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cweWX.png)

Then i need to add the columns to get 15

When I try to add them it adds all the rows before condensing them down.

Comment: What do you mean by `need to add the columns to get 15` ? get 15 rows ?

Comment: I need to add the sum of the columns, in the example I gave the total just happen to be 15. If you were add the columns before grouping you get 24 or something

Comment: I don't know if you need `result of code` for other purposes, but `SELECT SUM(type_value) FROM <your original query>` will get you the answer. My gut tells me that there is a more efficient way to get that answer, but sometime processor-seconds are worth less than the engineer-hours to optimize.

Comment: (1.75 * 4) + (3 *3) = 15 ?

Comment: correction and thank you....well it appears i cant not add in my own brain lol (1.75 * 4) + (3 *3) does not equal 15 its 16 SMH, however thank you to jerry and ken lee for pointing in the right direction and i was able to get it working..